# Camera preview always returns a 320x240 Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera

I am creating an image preview and I wished to get a very high picture resolution. However, and I don't know why, despite Galaxy Nexus supports a wide range of resolutions (I think the largest one is 1920x1080, but I can't remember if those are the exact values), when I save the picture, it says the info coming from the preview is of 320x240.

```
pixels.mCamera = getCameraInstance();
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
Size biggestSize = sizes.get(0);
double biggestPixels = biggestSize.width + biggestSize.height;
for (Size size : sizes) {
    double pixels = size.width * size.height;
    if (pixels > biggestPixels) {
        biggestSize = size;
        biggestPixels = pixels;
    }
}
// At this point, biggestSize is 1920x1080
float ratio = ((float) biggestSize.width)
                    / ((float) biggestSize.height);
params.setPreviewSize(biggestSize.width, biggestSize.height);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
setCameraDisplayOrientation(this, 0, mCamera);
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
LinearLayout innerWrapper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.innerWrapper);
LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) innerWrapper
                    .getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = (int) (layoutParams.height * ratio);
innerWrapper.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
preview.addView(mPreview);
```

That `innerWrapper` stuff is to show a square picture. `setCameraOrientation` turns the image to align with the ratio. When taking the picture I use autofocus and then...

```
mCamera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 1;
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                                            data.length, options);
                Bitmap finalBitmap;
                float ow = bitmap.getWidth();
                float oh = bitmap.getHeight();
                // At this point, ow and oh are 320 and 240
                float ratio = ow / oh;
                int fw, fh, x, y, angle;
                //It continues, but irrelevant
                ...
```

Is this anything related to the layout dimensions of the `FrameLayout` I use to hold the preview? Because I defined it to be of 350x350 dp, and this the preview should be bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me. The problem is that my `PictureCallback` is implemented as the `jpeg` parameter, not the `raw` one. Where, quoting the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29):

> The raw callback occurs when the raw image data is available (NOTE:
>   the data will be null if there is no raw image callback buffer
>   available or the raw image callback buffer is not large enough to hold
>   the raw image). The postview callback occurs when a scaled, fully
>   processed postview image is available (NOTE: not all hardware supports
>   this). The jpeg callback occurs when the compressed image is available.

Moving the whole `PictureCallback` to the second parameter of `mCamera.takePicture` instead of the third would be on the path to solve the issue. However, you'd need a `CallbackBuffer` to do so and change the code to adapt to the use of buffers. So for the first version I'll stick to low quality pictures.